# Detect collision of a circle

Tags: unity

I want to detect collision in every different color to this circle

[image]

Comment: Collisions with what? Only the other annulus segments, or other colliders, bodies, mouse clicks, etc? How are the segments moving, positioned? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply make use of Unity's built-in functionality of parenting and tagging to create one child for every section of the circle and then check the tag to see what part you hit.

Here's an image illustrating the setup (click for larger image):

[image: setup]

Then you can have a script on the parent `Circle` object that makes use of the `OnCollisionEnter2D` method:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if(coll.collider.tag == "Red")
    {
        // Hit red part of circle
     else if (coll.collider.tag == "Blue")
    {
        // Hit blue part of circle
    }
    // etc.
}
```

### Notes:

- Make sure to set the tag of the child objects using the `tag` dropdown.
- Make sure the parent `Circle` object has a `RigidBody2D`.

Comment: how can i add Polygon Collider 2d in specific colored area?thanks

Comment: @Aunog Press the "Edit Collider" button and manually edit the Collider to fit the area.